# "cannot find -lboost-system", but library exists on filesystem

Tags: c++, linker, g++

Here is the make command with associated error:

```
g++ -g -O2 -Wl,-rpath=../../../external/boost-1.55.0-x86_64-linux-gcc-4.8.2/lib -pthread -o xml_wrapper_tester xml_wrapper_tester-runner.o  -L../../../external/boost-1.55.0-x86_64-linux-gcc-4.8.2/lib -lboost-system ../xml_wrapper/.libs/libxml_wrapper.a -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost-system
```

Going into the directory where the make file is and ls -l the path specified to -L shows the library exists.

```
[mehoggan@localhost xml_wrapper_tester]$ ls -l ../../../external/boost-1.55.0-x86_64-linux-gcc-4.8.2/lib | grep system
-rw-rw-r--. 1 mehoggan mehoggan  217676 May  5 22:37 libboost_filesystem.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mehoggan mehoggan      29 May  5 22:37 libboost_filesystem.so -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mehoggan mehoggan  116955 May  5 22:37 libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 mehoggan mehoggan   49154 May  5 22:37 libboost_system.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mehoggan mehoggan      25 May  5 22:37 libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.55.0
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mehoggan mehoggan   20401 May  5 22:37 libboost_system.so.1.55.0
```

Why is it that boost_system cannot be found by g++?

Comment: Perhaps because you specified boost-system instead of boost_system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems to be with the `-lboost-system` argument you specified, which is indeed not in the folder you listed.

Try using `-lboost_system` instead.